# JavaFX Native libraries

Tags: swing, javafx, jnlp, java-web-start

I create a simple Java Map Scene in JavaFX. I put jfxrt.jar into my lib folder in project, but I also need native libraries to use some components: for example glass.dll on Windows and libglass.dylib on MacOsX. I have got few queston:

1. Where I should add these libliaries? To /rt/?
2. It is Swing application, and client start it by using Java WebStart. How can I add dependencies to these native libs?
3. What about x32 / x64 Windows versions? The jfxrt.jar is different for 32bit and 64bit system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where I should add these libliaries? To /rt/?

You could place the libraries in ../bin relative to where you have placed jfxrt.jar.  Haven't tried it, but I think it will work as that is the directory structure used by the JavaFX distributions.

Embedding the native libs in a Swing app delivered via a webstart package is not a [documented deployment option](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deployment_toolkit.htm).  Instead of doing that, I'd advise checking for JavaFX presence in your Swing app and, if JavaFX is not there launching a browser pointing to the JavaFX runtime [download and installation](http://www.java.com/en/javafx/) page - the instructions for which are [here](http://www.java.com/en/javafx/javafx_install.jsp).  For example:

```
try {
  new javafx.util.Pair("a","b"));
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
  java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.java.com/en/javafx/"));
}
```

> It is Swing application, and client start it by using Java WebStart. How can I add dependencies to these native libs?

If you app is still in development, and can be targeted for the JavaFX 2.2 release in a couple of months, then you could set the minimum version required for the app to JDK7u6 - which will include JavaFX 2.2 runtime libs - then you wouldn't have to worry about their distribution and the deployment scenarios are much, much simpler.

Not sure if JavaFX 2.1 embedded in Swing deployed via WebStart is supported (or would even work) outside of Windows.  You may want to wait for 2.2 for Mac and Linux webstart support for JavaFX applications.

> What about x32 / x64 Windows versions? The jfxrt.jar is different for 32bit and 64bit system.

If you app is launched from a browser, then whatever bits the browser has is the bits that are required for JavaFX and Java.  Most browsers today (at least under windows) are 32 bits, even if the user has a 64bit OS - so that is something to watch out for.  As you are using WebStart, it may not have the browser bit match dependence (in which case you should at least match the bit versions of JavaFX and Java).